# Contacts sync conflict with google and exchange

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, contacts, exchange-activesync

On my iPhone, I sync with my business Exchange account on one side and with my private Gmail account on the other side. This runs smoothly.

My contacts information, however, is centralized in Google Contacts. Thus, I can make contact information available on all other devices. Unfortunately, I discovered that the iPhone stores new contacts information randomly. How can set my iPhone to - by default - store new contacts in Google Contacts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the default Contact account for each of your iDevices to point to a single service (i.e. Exchange, iCloud, etc).

[The solution](http://transfer-iphone-contacts.blogspot.com/2012/04/icloud-contacts-not-syncing.html) along with some screenshots.